# Only the homepage works on a localhost version of Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, localhost

I have installed WAMP and set up a local version of my live Wordpress site, however only the admin area and homepage work.

I have done / tried the following things, as suggested in similar questions, but the issue persists:

- Changed siteurl in wp_options in phpMyAdmin to http://localhost/mysite
- Changed home in wp_options in phpMyAdmin http://localhost/mysite
- Updated wp-config to have the correct database login credentials
- Ensure URLs in Settings - Permalinks in Wordpress begin with http://localhost/mysite
- Clicked 'Save Changes' in Settings - Permalinks from the Wordpress backend
- Accessed from a browser that doesn't automatically redirect to https://localhost/mysite (which Chrome was doing)
- Toggled RewriteModule on in Apache Services in WAMP
- Restarted all services on WAMP
- Changed all instances of AllowOverride none to AllowOverride all in httpd.conf in WAMP
- Restarted all services on WAMP again
- Clicked 'Save Changes' in Settings - Permalins from the Wordpress backend again

On Firefox Private Browsing, any page except wp-admin/* and /mysite redirect to https://localhost, which gives an error message.

I have managed to stop the redirect to HTTPS, but the pages still don't work. In this case I'm presented with a butchered version of the localhost homepage.

Any advice on getting this sorted would be hugely appreciated.

**EDIT**

Images of two issues I am encountering.

Firstly, I get a butchered version of the localhost homepage when the browser does not redirect to https, and I follow a link from the functional homepage to another URLs (http://localhost/mysite/example) which functions on the live version:

[image: Butchered WAMP page]

On Firefox where it redirects to https I get the following error message:

[image: Firefox error]

Comment: Is the `<base />` tag set in your html? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: It wasn't, but it is now. I tried both `<base href="localhost/mysite">` and `<base href="http://localhost/mysite">` and neither worked: the browser still attempts to redirect to https and delivers an error message.

Comment: What is the error message? This information should always be part of your question.

Comment: My bad. I've edited my original question to include screenshots and descriptions of the two errors I'm encountering.

Comment: I fixed this with a bunch of tinkering, will write as a separate answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this after a bunch of increasingly experimental tinkering.

The thing that solved the issue was deleting the htaccess file, visiting Settings - Permalinks, and hitting Save Changes. This created a new htaccess file which has allowed me access to all URLs on the site.

Comment: awesome! Thank you for your fixing :D

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue. I have saved the 'settings->permalinks' page. it didn't solved my problem. Later I deactivated all the plugins one by one and I found the problem lied with one of my plugins.